# Django 4.1: How do I set Profile model's slug field's default value to username?

Tags: django, django-models, slug, django-users

I've created a profile model for [Django's default user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) and I want to create a slug for it so that it can be called using a username and not a user id or pk, I've tried this so far but I've achieved nothing, **I'm not asking you to complete the way I'm trying to achieve this but if there is a better way of doing it, Please tell me**


models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=user, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(User.objects.get(user__id = 1).username)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

from .views import UserCreateView, UserLoginView, UserProfileCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('u/<slug:slug>/edit_profile/', UserProfileCreateView.as_view(), name='edit_profile')
]
```

view.py:

```py
class UserProfileCreateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = UserProfileCreateForm
    template_name = 'auth/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Can you explain more what does not work or provide an error/stack trace? You should be able to access the username directly: `self.slug = slugify(self.username)`.

Comment: Import slugify method from [utils lib](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/): `from django.utils.text import slugify`

Comment: @Marco Unfortunately not, It's just blank, Even though I tried settings `blank=False` and it also raises no error!

Comment: Could you show your `UserProfileCreateView` view?